# How to Show multiple image share options of our Application like facebook?

Tags: android, image, android-manifest, share-intent

I am creating a social media application in which user can share images, videos, audios etc. I am successful in receiving the medias that shares from third party application by adding the below code in manifest file.

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.SendToActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now I want to show multiple icons of my application when a user try to share an image from their gallery like facebook(set as profile pic) to upload profile image directly. Please see the screenshot

[image: Like facebook multiple icons are shown]

Somebody please help me to show multiple icons of my application when a user try to share an image from their gallery.

Comment: Android Share Sheet - Check the section on [adding custom targets](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#adding-custom-targets) and the [receiving simple data from other apps](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive).

Comment: To add icons and labels check this page out: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#iconlabel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To provide custom icons and labels on a picker you need to add parameters to the intent filter on the manifest.
By default it uses the parent's icon and label.

You can override those as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile_icon" <!-- Custom icon -->
            android:label="Set as profile"> <!-- Custom label -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_story_icon" <!-- Custom icon -->
            android:label="Share as story"> <!-- Custom label -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Please note that this is a sample app that holds no logic or value.

Hope it helps :)